# Which access point? Unifi vs EnGenius

Tags: wifi

I am looking to purchase 30 access points to be used in a hotel project. They will be placed in the corridors; hence we don't want to see any antennas or ugly boxes hanging on the walls. The budget is a bit tight; Cisco probably won't fit.

I've found two companies which make aesthetic looking access points at affordable prices: Unifi and EnGenius. I am aware that these can only be managed by a management software which I am fine with.

Has anyone had any experience with these manufacturers? Can you compare one to the other?

Thanks

Comment: EnGenuis don't really have a competing product with UniFi Professional (right now, the EAP600 looks promising though); they both have 802.11af (PoE), but the UniFi has dual-band 2.4 and 5Ghz, which is most likely worth the increase in cost over the standard UniFi. Additionaly the UniFi Pro has a 1000Mw transmitter, vs 200 or 500 in the lower models (not sure about the EnGenuis, I can't find a quick specs on their transmitters)

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: I think that an overpowerful access point would do more harm than good. Unifi LR claims to have 600' range; I am not sure how most clients would send data back to the access point. Dual band is plus though as it would allow more users to connect at the same time.

Comment: You only get the maximum range _outdoors_ with _no obstructions_. Inside a hotel, your range is dramatically reduced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with those vendors specifically. However, for people diving in to wireless for the first time, I generally suggest that they might want to consider...

There are a couple of big-name vendors (that don't have Cisco price tags) that will come out and demo their products by doing a site-survey and actually install a complete system for you. Then if you like it, you buy the system. It's a great way to get a solid system installed at a good price. Just be aware that they won't do the cabling for you so that will be a separate effort.